# When having a Segmentation Fault change the message error shown

Tags: c++, datetime, error-handling, segmentation-fault, try-catch

I have the folowing code to convert a date to milliseconds:

```
long lond dateToMs(const char* text)
{
     std::tm tm = {};
     const char* snext = ::strptime(text, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
     auto time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm));
     return time_point.time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) + std::atof(snext) * 1000.0f;
}
```

When I have a date that dosen't exist For example: `40-10-2015 12:23:45.2354` the program shows the following message: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` Instead, I want to show something like `The introduced date it's not valid`. 
I have tryed a try..catch block as follows:

```
long long dateToMs(const char* text)
{
 try{
  std::tm tm = {};
  const char* snext = ::strptime(text, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm); 
  auto time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm)); 
  return time_point.time_since_epoch()/std::chrono::milliseconds(1)+std::atof(snext)*1000.0f;
 }
 catch(const std::exception &)
 {
    std::cout << "The introduced date it's not valid" << std::endl;
 };
}
```

But it shows the same error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, What I have to do to show the message error that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accounting for the possibility that `snext` will be null.

```
long long dateToMs(const char* text)
{
     std::tm tm = {};
     const char* snext = ::strptime(text, "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S", &tm);
     if ( snext )
     {
          auto time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm));
          return time_point.time_since_epoch() / std::chrono::milliseconds(1) + std::atof(snext) * 1000.0f;
     }
     else
     {
          std::cout << "The introduced date it's not valid";
     }


}
```

[Live sample](https://www.ideone.com/lb6S1v)

Comment: I have tryed this code and the appears the same `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I've seen that when you are trying to interact with the snext pointer, for example doing a std::cout<<snext<<std::endl; or if(snext) the program shows the error and stop executing

Comment: @david.t_92 I have added a link to demonstrate the code working.

Comment: Tank you, it works, the problem is tat i was using a flag when compiling